# Create a file in terminal using swift script

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I'm now playing with swift scripts and have bumped into something I cannot seem to find an answer to. Cutting to the chase, I'm trying to run an image comparison script that compares two images and outputs a file showing the differences. However, the problem is, I cannot seem to be able to force Xcode to create any sort of files, even a simple text ones as it prompts me an error:

`touch: /Users/CurrentUser/Desktop/TestExport/somethingelse.txt: Operation not permitted`

I've tried giving this folder a full permission access using "chmod 777" terminal line, sadly, with no avail.

The initial code I'm trying to execute is this:

```
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}


shell("touch", "/Users/CurrentUser/Desktop/TestExport/somethingelse.txt")
```

Do you have any ideas what can be done towards solving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the identical command work on the command line (in the Terminal)? Is "CurrentUser" the actual user name?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes. If I run this command in Terminal, it works just fine and the user name is as it is "CurrentUser". it somehow looks like Xcode is not allowed to create files.

Comment: It works for me. Is there any sandboxing involved?

Comment: In fact, it is. I'm pretty sure I've disabled it, but it might be that I've still missed something. Need to recheck. Thanks for pointing it out!